# Why the derivative of an unknown function is 1 in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations, derivative

Now, I am learning SymPy. While trying some code about differential equation, I defined `f` as a function as follows:

```
from sympy import *
f=symbols('f',cls=Function)
x,y=symbols('x,y')
```

While trying to write the first derivative w.r.t. `x` I wrote this:

```
diff(f,x)
```

Which gives always `1`. My question is Why? Does this mean that the default value of f is x? which is unlogic because when I try to find the derivative w.r.t. `y` it is also `1`. The logic answer is that it should be zero as I think.

Also, when I am trying to find the second derivative, it gives me an error that meaning that `f` is `2` and it cannot be `2`!!

```
diff(f,x,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-73-34a606e25841>", line 1, in <module>
    diff(f,x,2)

  File "C:\Users\osama\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\core\function.py", line 2503, in diff
    return f.diff(*symbols, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\osama\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\core\expr.py", line 3502, in diff
    return _derivative_dispatch(self, *symbols, **assumptions)

  File "C:\Users\osama\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\core\function.py", line 1947, in _derivative_dispatch
    return Derivative(expr, *variables, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\osama\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\sympy\core\function.py", line 1314, in __new__
    raise ValueError("First variable cannot be a number: %i" % v)

ValueError: First variable cannot be a number: 2
```

EDIT: SymPy Version = 1.8

I found the solution "from the code point of view" that I should type it as a `diff(f(x),x)` and `diff(f(x),x,2)` but this is not the question.

Comment: I get an error message "Since there are no variables in the expression f, it cannot be
differentiated." Please add the sympy version, mine is 1.3

Comment: @LutzLehmann 1.8

Comment: So something has been "improved" in sympy, changing a sensible error message to a dangerous default result.

Comment: This is actually a reported issue, with some more variants: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21655

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you. I think this closes the question

Answer (score 0):

**TESTED IN SYMPY 1.7.1**

It seems that if you do not provide an input to the function in its first parameter, the operation will be evaluated in a less symbolic form with dx-like = arg2, dy-like = arg3, and order = arg4.

```
diff(f, x, x) = 1      # == diff(f, x) == diff(f, x, x, 1)
diff(f, y, y) = 1      # == diff(f, y) == diff(f, y, y, 1)
diff(f, x, y) = diff(f, y, x) = 0
diff(f, x, x, 0) = x
diff(f, x, x, 1) = 1
diff(f, x, x, 2) = 0
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your point or not, but it seems like that the second argument is considered as the function definition itself. Try: `diff(f, x**2)`. Then the third parameter seems to be the variable to perform derivative with respect to it. And the fourth parameter is the order as you said.